# Flutter Error There's no constant named 'NORMAL' in 'WhiteSpace'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, constants

I have a small error in my project after upgrading flutter and packages. There's no constant named 'NORMAL' in 'WhiteSpace'.

```
style: {
        "body": Style(
            margin: Margins.zero,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            fontSize: FontSize(18.0),
            lineHeight: LineHeight(1.7),
            whiteSpace: WhiteSpace.NORMAL,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans'),
        "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6": Style(
            margin: Margins.all(textPadding == null ? 20.0 : textPadding!)),
        "figure": Style(margin: Margins.zero, padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
      },
```

It was working properly before I upgraded my packages and flutter sdk.

[image: Flutter Error after upgrade]

Thank You

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html/latest/style/WhiteSpace.html) of `flutter_html`, `WhiteSpace.NORMAL` is still there. You can try verifying this WhiteSpace is coming from the `flutter_html` library and it's not caused by conflicting imports, or you can try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` or you can try invalidating cache of Android Studio.

Comment: Checked everything. Nothing is working